# Counting changed lines of code over time in a repository

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to obtain the number of changed lines of code over a certain time period in a mercurial repository? Something along the lines of what [statsvn](http://www.statsvn.org/) does would be great, but anything counting the number of changed lines of code within 6 months will do (including a clever combination of arguments to hg log).

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/gource/ will do it and look pretty in the process.  :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [hg churn extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChurnExtension) is what you want.

You can get visual results with [hg activity](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ActivityExtension) or [hg chart](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChartExtension).

Answer (score 18):

**Edit**: `hg diff` and `hg log` both support a `--stat` option that can do this for you, only better and quicker.

---

I made an alias called `lines` to count changed lines (not necessarily lines of code) for me.  Try putting this alias in your .hgrc file:

```
[alias]
lines = !echo `hg log -pr $@ | grep "^+" | wc -l` Additions; echo `hg log -pr $@ | grep "^-" | wc -l` Deletions;
```

Then pass it the revision first, followed by any optional arguments:

`hg lines tip` or `hg lines 123:456 -u brian`

Sometimes you want to know the number of lines changed excluding whitespace-only changes.  This requires using `diff -w` underneath instead of `log -p`.  I set up a `linesw` alias for this:

```
#ignore whitespace
linesw = ![[ $1 =~ : ]] && r=$1 || r="$1~1:$1"; echo `hg diff -wr $r | grep "^+\([^+]\|$\)" | wc -l` Additions; echo `hg diff -wr $r | grep "^-\([^-]\|$\)" | wc -l` Deletions;
```

`hg linesw tip` or `hg lines 123:456`

Note they behave slightly differently because `diff` and `log` behave differently -- for example, `log` will take a `--user` parameter while `diff` will not, and when passing a range, `log` will show changes commited in the first revision given in the range, while `diff` will not.

This has only been tested using bash.

Comment: Don't use the hg log command. This also includes all changes in the 
 linear repo hostory between the two commit IDs, including commits that were not committed in the current branch.

Answer (score 11):

I needed to do this, and spent quite a bit of time with the hg churn extension and similar solutions.

In the end, I found that what worked best for me was CLOC (Count Lines of Code): http://cloc.sourceforge.net/

You can give it two folders containing two versions of a project, and it will count all of the lines that are the same, modified, added, removed. It recognises multiple languages and itemises code, comments and blank lines.

To use it, I pulled out the two versions of my code from Hg into two parallel folders, and then used cloc --diff   --ignore-whitespace

Comment: That's a nice solution to the "problem" as you just download one Perl file. Note the syntax is: `./cloc.pl --ignore-whitespace --ignore-case --diff <dir a> <dir b>`

Comment: its not a fast as git diff --shortstat, but it does a much better job of finding duplicate code that has been copied.